# How to decode a picture from java byte array

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, tomcat7, tomcat8

I get a byte array from the server and then convert it to imageView. The problem is that when I used tomkat maven plug everything was fine, but as soon as I started using tomkat version 8, it turned out that

```
BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray
```

**started returning null. Error (or rather, null) started to appear after using TomCat 8 and 9 (tried and 7) All code**

*I tried tomсat 7 8 9*

```
     // IMAGE MESSAGE
      //Android client 
          if (message.getImageMessage() != null) {
           MessageViewHolder2 holder = new MessageViewHolder2();
           LayoutInflater messageInflater = (LayoutInflater) 
           context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
           byte [] ar = message.getImageMessage().getByteArray();
           Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(ar , 0, ar.length);

           if (bmp!=null) {

            ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 10, out);
            byte[] byteArray = out.toByteArray();

            // MY IMAGE
            if (message.getImageMessage().isFromMe()) {
            // Convert bytes data into a Bitmap
            convertView = 
            messageInflater.inflate(R.layout.image_my_message_layout, null);
            holder.messageBody = (ImageView) 
            convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageMessageView);
            holder.messageBody.setImageBitmap(bmp);

            //Вычисляем ширину и высоту изображения
            double width = bmp.getWidth();
            double height = bmp.getHeight();

            double koef = height / 1000;
            int newWidht = (int) (width / koef);
            int newheight = (int) (height / koef);

            Bitmap bmHalf = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, newWidht, newheight, false);
            holder.messageBody.setImageBitmap(bmHalf);
        }
    }

 // Getting pictures on the server
 public  int size =1_000_000;
 int sizeFoto = 0;
 public  ByteBuffer bbuf = ByteBuffer.allocate(size);

 @OnMessage
 public void processUpload(ByteBuffer msg, boolean last, Session session) {

sizeFoto +=msg.array().length;
if(msg.remaining()!=1) {
    bbuf.put(msg);
}
else{
    System.err.println("Size : "+sizeFoto);
    bbuf.put(msg);
    sendBuf(bbuf);
}
```

}

Comment: This is android code. It doesn't run into Tomcat. The documentation says: "Returns: The decoded bitmap, or null if the image could not be decoded.". So the image could not be decoded, probably because the array you pass as argument is incorrect, or partial, or corrupted somehow. But we have no idea at all of how you obtained this byte array in the first place. So we can't help.

Comment: But this code works on maven